# add contacts from address book to FBFriendPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am new to iOS. I have managed to get FBFriendPickerViewController work. However, I will like to develop an ios apps that integrated all the contact listings (e.g. from facebook, address book, email, etc) in one single view. And since FBFriendPickerViewController provided an existing table view for it, how do i add the other contact listings to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can use FBFriendPickerViewController for this. You need to develop your own tableViewController and add facebook contacts, addressbook contacts and other contacts in your controller's array and make it as datasource for your tableview.

For getting facebook friends, you need to use Facebook sdk for ios and do proper authorization and fetch friends.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

FBFriendPickerViewController is not a right choice, you should get the authorised token with permission for getting the email_id, and contact_no and same for other API like google and your address book too then you can present this data using tableviewcontroller